# Get deleted user information from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to get a user name of the user deleted from sharepoint? I have the id of the deleted user. I need this since I want to present a more user friendly information taken from the audit logs. There I have only the id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the information in the content database (the UserInfo table), I'm not sure wether you can get it from the object model though.

Remember Microsoft does not recommend directly querying the database though...